# ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '\node_modules\@fullcalendar\common'

Tags: angular, npm, fullcalendar

I'm trying to build or serve my Angular project, but I keep getting the following error:

'An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '\node_modules@fullcalendar\common'
See "\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-gMA9kN\angular-errors.log" for further details.'

I've tried deleting the node_modules directory and running npm install again, but the error persists. I'm using the FullCalendar package in my project. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?

**Version**

```
Angular CLI: 13.0.4
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: npm 8.16.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1303.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular      13.3.10
@angular-devkit/core               13.3.10
@angular-devkit/schematics         13.0.4
@angular/cdk                       12.1.4
@angular/cli                       13.0.4
@angular/google-maps               13.3.9
@angular/material                  12.1.4
@angular/material-moment-adapter   12.1.4
@schematics/angular                13.0.4
rxjs                               6.6.7
typescript                         4.4.4
```

**Dependecies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "12.1.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "12.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "13.0.3",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^6.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/moment": "^6.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/rrule": "^6.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.0.2",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.11",
    "@ngneat/transloco": "2.22.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.31.0",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.1.1",
    "crypto-js": "3.3.0",
    "highlight.js": "11.1.0",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-apexcharts": "1.7.1",
    "ng-dynamic-component": "10.1.0",
    "ngx-cookieconsent": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-markdown": "13.1.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "16.2.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.2",
    "quill": "1.3.7",
    "rrule": "2.6.8",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "tslib": "2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read and understand the error message. It means, that no file or directory in `node_modules/@fullcalendar/common` is. And if you habe a look in your dependencies or in the node_modules folder, you won't find anything with that name there.

So you still need to install that. With *npm* the install-command will look like:

`npm i @fullcalendar/common`

After that, you will be able to build or serve your angular project.

Package: [@fullcalendar/common](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fullcalendar/common)

Answer (score 0):

The package for full calender is missing, when you do an npm install, the package is not downloading. It might be due to the package.lock.json,

Delete ***node_modules* and *package.lock.json*** then do an **npm install**

Comment: What do you mean with "*The package for full calender is missing,…*"? You can see that several packages from `@fullcalendar` are added, just `common` not, like the error message says.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: but how can be sure that rest of the packages scoped @fullcalender is installed, that info is not provided, when the program tries to to access @fullcalender/common and it not present, it can be the starting point. So better do a full re installation, as the rest of the packages might also be missing.